# Openshift Nodejs Socket.io issue, But 200 Ok response

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift, redhat

I have deployed below code in OpenShift Cloud platform by Red-hat for NodeJs chat application, I am not getting any error in Console(F12) and response code as Ok 200..but the application is not working

Server(you can find complete source at https://github.com/varund29/openshift/blob/master/index.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { origins:'http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000' });
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatmessage', function (msg) {
        console.log('index.js(socket.on)==' + msg);
        io.emit('chatmessage', msg);
    });
});

server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);
```

Client(you can find complete source at https://github.com/varund29/openshift/blob/master/index.html)

```
src="http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js  
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" 

     var socket = io.connect('http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000');
        $('button').click(function (e) {
            console.log('index.html($(button).click)=' + $('#m').val());
            socket.emit('chatmessage', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chatmessage', function (msg) {
            console.log('index.html(socket.on)==' + msg);
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
```

Html body is

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: i took reference for the above from the http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I ran your code I got the following errors in my log files on my gear on OpenShift Online:

```
Option log level is not valid. Please refer to the README.
Option polling duration is not valid. Please refer to the README.
```

So I commented out the following lines in your `index.js` file:

```
io.set('log level', 1);                    // reduce logging
io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
io.set("polling duration", 10);
```

And it seems to be working fine now.  You can test it here: http://nodejs-cdaley.rhcloud.com/
And you can view the code here: https://github.com/developercorey/nodejs

Comment: Please tell how can i find log files in OpenShift.

Comment: thanks, now its working fine. and i found issue is if "dependencies": { "socket.io": "~9.6.0" } its not working. working fine with "dependencies": { "socket.io": "1.2.0" } –

Comment: You can find your log files by following these instructions: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html